# Create a csv with multiple entries in list

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

I am using csv package to generate csv with lists and 'zip' to connect two list at same index. Now if variable 'name' has lists inside meaning multiple names for each 'file' and want to add in each corresponding row. Only thing there can be multiple names for each file .

variable file and list are lists:

one element from 'file' connects to one element of 'name' bu now that one element of 'name' is a list but want it in different columns in csv.

```py
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(zip(file, name))
```

The below is current output

```
1.txt,"['XYZ', 'ABC', 'PQR']"
2.txt,"['rtgs', 'gfd']"
```

The below is expected

```
1.txt,'XYZ', 'ABC', 'PQR'
2.txt,'rtgs', 'gfd'
```

So I want separate columns for each value in second column

Comment: Please poat an example of what your data looks like and what you want your transformed data to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to flatten the list of lists into a list of strings

```
name = [', '.join(n) for n in name] 
writer.writerows(zip(file, name))
```

or just use a loop and write each row individually

```
for n, names in zip(file, name):
    writer.writerow([n, ', '.join(names))]
```

Note: putting commas within a column of a CSV isn't the best idea